# 3NF Normalization In mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, workbench, 3nf

Morning Guys,

Im struggling to see how these following tables can be broken up into 3NF, I Know the rules based on normalizing but cannot seen any data that needs to be moved here is how the tables look:

PlaylistID, PlaylistName, TrackID, Trackname, AlbumID, AlbumTitle, GenreID, GenreName, TrackSeconds, TrackBytes

Comment: Is that a list of tables, of columns, or what? Details here are insufficient for any type of answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is a list of the column names of one table namely  "Music-information"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but here goes

You should create a separate table for each ID column... and then move into that table all the related columns:

```
Playlist(ID, Name)
Track(ID, Name, Seconds, Bytes, AlbumID, GenreID)
Album(ID, Title)
Genre(ID, Name)
```

Since you will probably want to have the same track in more than one playlist, you need a many-to-many relation, which you should handle with a relation table:

```
PlaylistTrack(PlaylistID, TrackID)
```

This satisfies the 3NF, as the playlist name, the album title and the genre name are not repeated on multiple rows.